# Does Camera class work well now in android? (API 29)

Tags: android, camera

It says that Camera class has been deprecated since API 21.

I wonder if there is a problem with compatibility if I use camera class in **API 29.**

Can I still writing an app using the Camera class instead of the Camera2 class (in the **TargetSdkVersion 29**)?

If I use the deprecated Camera, will the app still run on all APIs now?

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated means "*it is preferable not to more use this because the compatibility is not more guaranteed*".
So using old Camera API could work on old devices but (maybe) not in some other new, or viceversa.
The result is unpredictable, so **it's better to NOT use a deprecated thing** in newer versions.